# Solve the triple integral

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $V = \{(x,y,z) \mid x^2+y^2 \le 4x, z \le x^2+y^2\}$

I need to solve the following triple integral:
$$\iiint_V \,dx\,dy\,dz$$
What I've done:
$$\iiint_V \,dx\,dy\,dz = \int_0^{16}dz \bigg( \int_{V_1}dx\,dy + \int_{V_2}dx\,dy \bigg),$$
where $V_1 = \{(x,y,z) \mid 0 \le x \le \frac{\sqrt{z}}{4}, -\sqrt{4-(x-2)^2} \le y \le \sqrt{4-(x-2)^2} \}$
and $V_2 = \{(x,y,z) \mid \frac{\sqrt{z}}{4} \le x \le \sqrt{z}, -\sqrt{z-x^2} \le y \le \sqrt{z-x^2} \}$

But it looks so ugly, I think I should use polar (or other) substitution. How I can use it in this case?

Comment: Just about anytime I see regions bounded by things like $x^2 + y^2$ in a calculus class, my first thought is to use cylindrical or spherical coordinates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. Use cylindrical coordinates. Note that
$$ x^2+y^2 \le 4x\implies r\leq 4\cos(\theta).$$
Moreover I guess that you need also $z\geq 0$. Then
$$V=\int_{\theta=-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_{r=0}^{4\cos(\theta)}\int_{z=0}^{r^2} 1\, (dz\, r dr\, d\theta).$$

Comment: Yes, $z \ge 0$. Thank yout!

Comment: Did you forget $|r|$ under integral (instead of $1$)?

Comment: There is one $r$ in the differential,

Comment: Ok, I didn't notice it :)